# How do I make an accordion just using two buttons?

Tags: jquery, html, accordion, jquery-ui-accordion

I wrote a script for a jQuery accordion menu. Currently the way it works is there are four different menu buttons and when you click each one a new section is revealed. I want to alter the script so that there are only two buttons one that moves the accordion forward and one back. So if there are five different sections one button advances to the next section and one goes to the previous. I know this involves the .each function but I'm not sure how to integrate it. Below is my current script and the HTML.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            $('.tabs a').click(function(){
                var $this = $(this);
                $('.panel').hide();
                $('.tabs a.active').removeClass('active');
                $this.addClass('active').blur();
                var panel = $this.attr('href');
                $(panel).fadeIn(1300);
                return false;
            });//end click
            $('.tabs li:first a').click();
        }); // end ready

<ul class="tabs"><!--Added class tabs and panel 1, 2, 3, 4-->
            <li><a href="#panel1" class="">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#panel2" class="">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#panel3" class="">Work</a></li>
            <li><a href="#panel4" class="">Contact Me</a></li>
        </ul>

 <div class='panel' id='panel1'>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut
                laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation
                ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut
                laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam.
            </p>
        </div>

        <div class='panel' id='panel2'>
            <p>hi
            </p>
        </div>

        <div class='panel' id='panel3'>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut
                laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation
                ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut
                laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam.
            </p>
        </div>

        <div class='panel' id='panel4'>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut
                laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation
                ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut
                laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam.
            </p>
        </div>

        <div class='panel' id='panel5'>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut
                laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation
                ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut
                laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam.
            </p>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this 
http://jsfiddle.net/69D96/

HTML

```
<ul>
    <li><a class="control" id="prev" href="#">Prev</a></li>
    <li><a class="control" id="next" href="#">Next</a></li>
</ul>

<div class='panel' id='panel1'>
 1
</div>

<div class='panel' id='panel2'>
2
</div>

<div class='panel' id='panel3'>
 3  
</div>

<div class='panel' id='panel4'>
4
</div>
```

And JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.control').click(function(){
        //handle click
        var $this = $(this);
        $('.panel').hide();

        var panel = $this.attr('href');
        $(panel).fadeIn(1300);

        // update href of next and prev
        var panelCount = $('.panel').size();
        var panelI = parseInt( panel.replace('#panel','') );
        var prevI = panelI -1;
        if (prevI <1 ) prevI=1;
        var nextI = panelI +1;
        if( nextI >= panelCount) nextI = panelCount -1;

        $('#prev').attr('href', '#panel' + prevI);
        $('#next').attr('href', '#panel' + nextI);        

        return false;
    }).eq(0).attr('href', '#panel1').click(); 

});
```

Comment: Hey Michael I just noticed one problem. The 5th panel never shows up and I'm not quite sure why because your code is written in a way that it can be an infinite amount of panels right?

Comment: Nevermind I got it. I just had to add a 6th Div. Thanks again.